# Difference between 本当に and 全然 in a negative sentence

Tags: syntax, adverbs

I want to translate something like the following:

> I watched a movie with together with my friends.
>   *Not at all* did I watch it *alone*.

Where the *"not at all"* is supposed to express obvious sarcasm regarding the *alone*-ness.
**EDIT:** *Obvious sarcasm* because *"I"* doesn't really have friends, except maybe imaginary ones etc.
The exact wording isn't really important. It should just sound like a complete and obvious rejection of *alone*. (If that makes any sense...)

So my attempt was:

> 友達{ともだち}と一緒{いっしょ}に映画{えいが}を見{み}た。
>   全然{ぜんぜん}一人{ひとり}では見{み}なかったよ。

I was told that this would not have my intended meaning because 全然{ぜんぜん} relates to just 見{み}なかった and not the whole sentence. So it would mean *"Alone, I did not at all watch it."*
As an alternative the following would be possible:

> …
>   本当{ほんとう}に一人{ひとり}では見{み}なかったよ。

Since this is supposed to be a correction, I understand this to translate as *"I really did not watch it alone."* and not, analogously, as *"Alone, I really did not watch it."*

1. If everything I'm assuming is correct, why do those two adverbs translate differently in this way, that is, why do they relate to different parts of the sentence? If not, what are my mistakes?
2. What would be the best translation of my original sentence? Maybe

   > 友達{ともだち}と一緒{いっしょ}に映画{えいが}を見{み}た、全然{ぜんぜん}一人{ひとり}ではなく。

   ?

Comment: I'm a native speaker of AmE, and the sentence "not at all did I watch it alone" seems really strained to me...

Comment: Is it understandable? What whould be better?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say in English, then +sarcasm, then how to express the base sentence in Japanese, +some form of humor... Maybe "there's no way I would watch it alone"?

Comment: Does my edit make it clear(er)?

Comment: Do you mean that the speaker is desperately _pretending_ having friends? And it smells that this post should be divided into two distinct questions...

Comment: The word order thing makes no sense insofar as "alone, I really did not watch it" is basically non-grammatical in English. Do you want something equally non-grammatical in Japanese?

Comment: @broccoliforest Yes, that's what I mean. The first question is the more important one. If the second one isn't easily answered I might as well ask it seperately...

Comment: @virmaior The word order and punctuation in those "explanations" is on purpose, to show how I think the sentence structure is. I.e. "Alone, I really did not watch it." is supposed to mean "I was alone and I really did not watch it." with emphasis on the second part. So no, the translation should be correct.

Comment: @en_ I see. Then I think you should leave your first question here, and open a new one for your second one. It's not so much difficult (rather easier than the first one), but the two topics are just clearly irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure I got the full meaning what you tried to show us in your examples, I think the difference between `本当に……ない` and `全然……ない` seems already obvious in your own translation.

As you said, `本当に` means *really*, while `全然` means *at all*. Thus naturally, the former wants to modify the whole *event*, and the latter, the *negation*. Put simply, `全然` always looks for the closest "not", and `本当に` looks for the closest predicate.

Now if the sentence has only one "not":

> **全然**一人ではできない。 ≈ 一人では**全然**できない。
>   Both roughly means "I **definitely** ca**n't** do it alone."

But,

> **全然**書けないわけではない。 *It's not that I can't write **at all**.*
>   ≠ 書けないわけでは**全然**ない。 *It's **definitely** not that I can't write.*

On the other hand, `本当に` is:

> **本当に**一人では危険だ。 ***Trust me**, It's dangerous (going) alone.* (i.e. "it is dangerous alone" is real.)
>   ≠ 一人では**本当に**危険だ。 *It's **really** dangerous (when you go) alone.* (i.e. "be dangerous" is real.)

So you could say (a) `全然一人では見なかった。` is grammatically parallel to (b) `一人では本当に見なかった。`, but not to (c) `本当に一人では見なかった。`

Last but not least, I copied your example in (a), but I have to say the sentences (a) and (b) doesn't sound really natural to me.

---

For your second question, actually, if I were in the speaker's shoes, I wouldn't use either of those constructions. I'd instead say:

> （別に）一人で見たわけじゃない（し／もん／から）。
>   （別に）一人なんかじゃなかった（し／もん／から）。

I still can't grasp the nuance of your "obvious sarcasm", but as you may know, 別に also is a typical [tsundere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere) expression to deny an obvious fact.

Comment: まあ、質問者の英語はなんか以外から、答えにくいと思います。

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had something similar to your answer vaguely in my mind. I think it's clear to me now.

Comment: I accept this answer. If someone were to answer my second question I guess a comment here would be alright. It's actually not that important...

Comment: @broccoli forest: Thank you for answering my second question. I think this is actually quite close to what I wanted to say, good mind reading :)